# Proofs for polynomial divisons

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I've got a couple of theorems that I must prove, but I'm completely stumped. Could someone help me out?

1. Prove: If P(x) can be divided by Q(x), then it can be divided by cQ(x), where c - any non zero number.
2. Prove: If the degrees of P and Q are the same ( equal), then P(x) can be divided by Q(x) then and only then, if Q(x)=cP(x), where c - any non zero number.
3. Prove: If c - any non zero number. then polynomials P(x) and cP(x) have the same divisors

I know from simple logic, that they are all true, but I'm bad at writing logic in math proofs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "number" you mean either "real number" or "complex number"; in fact, most of these statements are true in much greater generality (other classes of numbers).

1. The statement "$P(x)$ can be divided by $Q(x)$" means that there exists a polynomial $R(x)$ such that $Q(x)R(x) = P(x)$. In order to show that $P(x)$ can also be divided by $cQ(x)$, you need to find a polynomial $S(x)$ such that $(cQ(x))S(x) = P(x)$. Try using the $R(x)$ you know exists, and the fact that $c\neq 0$.
2. Again, you know that there is a polynomial $R(x)$ such that $Q(x)R(x)=P(x)$. What do you know about the degree of a polynomial product? That is, if the degree of $f(x)$ is $n$ and the degree of $g(x)$ is $m$, what is the degree of $f(x)g(x)$?
3. Show that if $Q(x)$ divides $P(x)$, then it also divides $cP(x)$. Then use this to show that anything that divides $cP(x)$ also divides $\frac{1}{c}\left(cP(x)\right)$ to get that $P(x)$ and $cP(x)$ have the same divisors: that is, that $Q(x)$ divides $P(x)$ if and only if it divides $cP(x)$. For the second part (that a divisor of $cP(x)$ is a divisor of $P(x)$) you'll need to use that $c\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The sought divisibility results are special cases of this simple

**Divides Product Rule** $\ $ Let $\rm\ a,b,c,d\in R $ any ring.

Then $\rm\quad\ \ a|b,\ \ c|d\ $ in $\rm\:R\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ ac|bd\ $ in $\rm\:R\:. $

**Proof** $\rm\ \ \ b/a,\ d/c \ \in\ R\ \Rightarrow\ (bd)/(ac)\in R\:.\quad$ **QED**

Now let's apply this Rule to derive the sought results in $\rm\ R = K[x],\ K\ $ a field.
Below I give the main steps, omitting trivial cases such as when $\rm\:p\:$ or $\rm\:q = 0\:.$

1. $\rm c|1,\ q|p\ \Rightarrow\ cq|p\ $ by the Rule (in a field $\rm\ K,\ c\ne 0\ \Rightarrow\ 1/c\in K\ \Rightarrow\ c|1\ $ in $\rm\:K\:).$
2. If $\rm\ deg\ p = \deg\ q\ $ then $\rm\ q|p \iff\ q = c\: p\ $ for some $\rm\ 0 \ne c\in K\:.$
   $\rm(\Leftarrow)\ \ c|1,\ p|p\ \Rightarrow\ cp|p\ $ by the Rule (or $\rm\ q \to p\ $ in 1).
   $\rm(\Rightarrow)\ \ p = q\:r\ \Rightarrow\ \deg\ r = \deg\ p - \deg\ q = 0\ \Rightarrow\ r\in K\:.$
3. $\rm\ q|p\ \iff\ q|cp\ $
   $\rm(\Leftarrow)\ \ q|cp|p\ $  by $\rm q \to p$ in 1 and "divides" transitivity ($\rm b = c\ \ne 0\:$ in Rule)
   $\rm(\Rightarrow)\ \  1|c,\ q|p\ \Rightarrow\ q|cp\ $ by the Rule.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working over complex numbers,

Hint: Try using the fundamental theorem of algebra.